# StatusBar not transparent on adjust pan

Tags: android

Need some help, have lost all my day trying to figure this out with no success.

When the keyboard shows up it pushes the layout up and the status bar becomes transparent.

[The effect i have is the same saw in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384134/adjustpan-pushing-my-layout-and-hiding-status-bar)

And i want the status bar to keep the color that it had.

How can i stop the status bar become transparent when using adjustspan? 
Is there a FLAG that makes the statusbar never transparent in any circunstance?

The android version i am testing is 5.0.

Comment: To solve this i used <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item> on my styles.xml and the status bar color became OS native and it worked.